# AWS SNS services failed send messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

Hey I try send my topic (with 1-5 people) on AWS console and it`s work but when I add many subscribers (500 or more) I have got failed response and nobody receive the message.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure the IAM key you have used in the code has required permissions? I usually assign full SNS access

Comment: What type of subscriptions are they (Email, SMS, Push)? Are they the same type as the 1-5 that work?

Comment: This is my own account and have all permission,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it,
**to resolve this must to be increase limit**  (By default, the spend limit is set to 1.00 USD) 
Setting Preferences (Console)
Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SNS console at [https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home][1].

1. In the console menu, set the region selector to a region that
   supports SMS messaging.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Text messaging (SMS)**.
3. On the **Text messaging (SMS)** page, choose **Manage text messaging**
   preferences.
4. On the Text messaging preferences page, for Default message type,
   select the type of SMS message that you will usually send:

   **Promotional** (default) – Noncritical messages, such as marketing
   messages. Amazon SNS optimizes the message delivery to incur the
   lowest cost.

   **Transactional** – Critical messages that support customer
   transactions, such as one-time passcodes for multi-factor
   authentication. Amazon SNS optimizes the message delivery to achieve
   the highest reliability.

   You can override this setting when you send a message.
5. For **Account spend limit**, type the maximum amount in USD that you
   want to spend on SMS messages each calendar month. When Amazon SNS
   determines that sending an SMS message would incur a cost that
   exceeds your spend limit for that month, Amazon SNS stops publishing
   SMS messages within minutes.

**Or contact to Support, it will take 3-5 days**

goodluck :)